# How to add extra columns to Room entity when creating from pre-populated Database?

Tags: android, android-room, android-database

I am creating a room database from DB inside asset folder.

```
database = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, "x.db")
        .createFromAsset("databases/x.db")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .build()
```

With an Entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "x")
data class BibleDatas(
        @NotNull @ColumnInfo(name = "age") var name: Int,
        @NotNull @ColumnInfo(name = "name") var age: String,
        @Nullable @ColumnInfo(name = "saved") var saved: Int
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @NotNull @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int
    )
```

my asset folder DB has columns name and age, and saved column am creating from dynamically.

But am getting an error saying

```
Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: 
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='x', columns={age=Column{age='age', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, saved=Column{age='saved', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, name=Column{age='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='x', columns={age=Column{age='age', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, name=Column{age='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

[Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035497/pre-packaged-database-has-an-invalid-schema-error)

Comment: can you please send the error here? so i can check and let you know the solution.

Comment: can you please send the error here? so i can check and let you know the solution.